# Missing .html file for Blazor .Net 8 Web App - When published with JetBrains Rider

Tags: .net-core, blazor, hosting, jetbrains-rider

Am i supposed to create one from another file, or?

I am hosting through GoDaddy, and the page is somewhat loading so its definitely pushing to the host... But theres no index.html in the wwwroot folder which is causing issues, and when. I create one from app.razor it doesn't do anything but show that page.

heres my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="_content/Blazor.Bootstrap/blazor.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="RDL.styles.css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Comfortaa:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet />
</head>

<body>
<Routes />
<div id="app">Loading...</div>
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Add chart.js reference if chart components are used in your application. -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.0.1/chart.umd.js" integrity="sha512-gQhCDsnnnUfaRzD8k1L5llCCV6O9HN09zClIzzeJ8OJ9MpGmIlCxm+pdCkqTwqJ4JcjbojFr79rl2F1mzcoLMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<!-- Add chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js reference if chart components with data label feature is used in your application. -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.2.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js" integrity="sha512-JPcRR8yFa8mmCsfrw4TNte1ZvF1e3+1SdGMslZvmrzDYxS69J7J49vkFL8u6u8PlPJK+H3voElBtUCzaXj+6ig==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="_content/Blazor.Bootstrap/blazor.bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

The template "Blazor Web App", which you mentioned your app is, creates 2 projects; the ASP.Net server and a Blazor WASM client. Unlike the "Blazor WebAssembly Standalone" template, "Blazor Web App" does not have an index.html file. Instead the primary html file is a part of the server project under Components and named App.razor.

A "Blazor Web App" cannot be hosted on a static host. The server project needs to run on the host server to serve the Blazor WASM client.

Not sure why your project is not working given the information at hand but that should explain why you don't have an index.html file and maybe help you understand the hosting model for a "Blazor Web App".

Comment: can you verify Rider produces two projects? When I create a new Blazor Web App it only creates the server, not the client like VS correctly does